# Solving Laplace's Equation on $(-\infty, 0)\times S^1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, periodic-functions

I'm interested in solving
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta u(x,\theta) = 0 & x < 0 \\
u(0,\theta) = f(\theta)
\end{cases}$$
for some sufficiently nice prescribed $f$, and $u$ periodic in $\theta$ with period $2\pi$. Here $x$ and $\theta$ are both real. I've tried considering an ansatz of the form $u(x,\theta) = a(x)\sin(\theta)$. Plugging this into the PDE gives $a''(x) - a(x) = 0$, so $a(x) = e^x$. But then the boundary condition implies that $a(0) = f(\theta)/\sin(\theta)$, and we are in trouble unless $f(\theta) \equiv 0$. I also tried an ansatz of the form $u(x,\theta) = a(x)f(\theta)$, but plugging this into the PDE gives $\frac{a''}{a} = -\frac{f''}{f}$, which I'm not sure how to handle.

I also considered using Green's function for the halfspace. If we did not require $u$ to be periodic in $\theta$, then we would be able to write down the solution
$$u(x,\theta) = -\frac{x}{\pi}\int \frac{f(\eta)}{x^2 + (\theta - \eta)^2}\,d\eta,$$
but it's not clear to me how to modify this to make it periodic.

Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to denote the position vector, $\mathbf{r}$? And in that case do you mean $e^{\Vert \mathbf{r} \Vert}$ by $e^x$?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that $x$ and $\theta$ are both real scalars.

Comment: The $(x,\theta)$ is a bit confusing.... Why are you combining Cartesian and polar coordinates?

Comment: Because I am interested in solutions on $(-\infty,0)\times S^1$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle. Here the Laplacian is in $x$ and $\theta$, i.e., $\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{\theta\theta}$.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what was meant by $S^1$. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Use [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations)
$$u(x,\theta) = X(x)\Theta(\theta),$$
as you have noticed, then note that in the resulting
$$\frac{X''}{X} = -\frac{\Theta''}{\Theta} = \lambda,$$
both sides must be the same constant, giving you the two ODEs
$$
\begin{align}
\Theta'' &= -\lambda \Theta,\qquad\Theta(0) = \Theta(2\pi) \\
X'' &= \lambda X.
\end{align}
$$

When we solve the first ODE, we should get
$$
\Theta(\theta) = A\cos(\sqrt\lambda\theta)+B\sin(\sqrt\lambda\theta),
$$
assuming $\lambda>0$.
From $\Theta(0)=\Theta(2\pi)$, we get that $\lambda$ has to be a positive perfect square, $n^2$. We cannot determine anything more about $n$ yet, apart from it being an integer. However, note that changing the sign of $n$ does not affect the solution, so WLOG, we can assume $n > 0$.

The other cases ($\lambda<0$ and $\lambda=0$) are straightforward;  you will find that $\lambda<0$ is incompatible with $\Theta(0)=\Theta(2\pi)$, and that $\lambda=0$ fits in nicely with our existing solutions.

$$
\begin{align}
\Theta_n(\theta) &= A_n \cos(n\theta) + B_n \sin(n\theta)&n>0\\
\Theta_0(\theta) &= A_0 &n=0
\end{align}$$

We can then solve the second ODE:
$$
\begin{align}
X_n(x) &= C_ne^{nx} + D_ne^{-nx}& n>0,\\
X_0(x) &= C_0 + D_0x &n=0.
\end{align}$$

Taking linear combinations, we get a bunch of solutions to the PDE (ignoring the initial conditions):
$$
\begin{align}
u(x,\theta) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Theta_n(\theta) X_n(x) \\
&= C_0 + D_0 x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (A_n \cos(n\theta) + B_n \sin(n\theta))(C_ne^{nx} + D_ne^{-nx})
\end{align}
$$
Normally, there is also a boundary condition of the form $\lim_{x\to-\infty}u(x,\theta)=0$ or $u_x(0,\theta) = g(\theta)$. If we had the first condition, we could set all the $D_n=0$.

At this point, so long as $f(\theta)$ has a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) (which we know because it is sufficiently nice), we can satisfy the initial conditions.

Comment: So I tried something like that, but I'm still having trouble accounting for the boundary condition, which tells us that $X(0)\Theta(\theta) = f(\theta)$ for some given $f$. Then we might want $X(0) = 1$ and have $\Theta(\theta) = f(\theta)$, but then we're not guaranteed that $\Theta''  =-\lambda\Theta$, which is where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: @Phil I'll add the next steps: ignore the boundary condition involving $f(\theta)$ until the very end; focus on getting an infinite number of solutions to the $\Theta$ ODE, and thus, the entire PDE. Then use linear combinations to get your final answer.

Comment: Ah, this is perfect, thank you so much!